# How to print/render in a table Firebase information REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Before posting I always google, youtube, forums or try to figure it by myself or even check other people questions that are similar but I'm stuck sadly.

So I'm using firestore database, the user can create a "student" and the data is the firestore is saved like this:

[image]

It saves the course, Name, school, and the UID of the person that create it. So far I have no problems importing that information to the firestore now the issue is to bring it back in a table, I do not understand why is not being printed.

The console Log is printing all the students 1 by 1 + all the students in the array (is cause is going through all the info)

[image]

Now as you can see the table is empty! and I do not understand WHY!!! *Very frustrated*

This are snips of the code that are relevant:

- DB part:

```
useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes')
        .get().then((snapshot) => {
                   (snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                      const data = doc.data();
                      estudiantes.push(data)
                      
                     console.log(doc.data());
                     console.log(estudiantes)
            }))
        })
    }, []);
```

- Map/Rendering

```
<tbody>
                {estudiantes.map((e) => (

                        <tr >
                        <td>

                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        </td>

                        <td >{e.name}</td>
                        <td >{e.school}</td>
                        <td >{e.grade}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                     ))}
                </tbody>
```

- Whole Code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth, db } from './firebase';
import "./ListadoEstudiantes.css"
import data from "./mock-data.json"
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Checkbox } from '@material-ui/core';

function ListadoEstudiantes({user}) {

    const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);
    const history = useHistory("");

    const crearEstudiante = () => {
          history.push("/Crear_Estudiante");
      }

      const realizarPedidos = () => {
        history.push("/Crear_Pedidos");
    }
    
    const estudiantes = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('usuarios').doc(user.uid).collection('estudiantes')
        .get().then((snapshot) => {
                   (snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                      const data = doc.data();
                      estudiantes.push(data)
                      
                     console.log(doc.data());
                     console.log(estudiantes)
            }))
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="listadoEstudiantes"> 
        <div className="estudiantes_container">
            <h1 className = "estudiantes_container_h1">Listado de estudiantes</h1>
            <button onClick={crearEstudiante} className = "crear_estudiante_boton">Crear Estudiantes</button>
            <h3 className = "estudiantes_container_h3">*Para realizar su pedido seleccione a los estudiantes</h3>
            <div className ="tableContainer">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr className="Lista">
                        <th>
                            <input type="checkbox"></input>
                        </th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Colegio</th>
                        <th>Grado</th>
                        <th>Accion</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {estudiantes.map((e) => (

                        <tr >
                        <td>

                        <input onChange = {(event) => {
                            let checked = event.target.checked;
                        }} 
                        
                        type="checkbox" checked = "">
                        </input>
                        </td>

                        <td >{e.name}</td>
                        <td >{e.school}</td>
                        <td >{e.grade}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        </tr>
                     ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

            <div className="space" />
            <button onClick={realizarPedidos} className = "crear_estudiante_boton">Realizar Pedidos</button>
            <div className="space" />
      </div>

      </div>
    )
}

export default ListadoEstudiantes
```

I think that's it, the user is from the Firestore database also the **data** that I'm importing is a fake data that I used to test the table (and renders with no issues) that can be ignored.

This is how it looks on the fake data and how it should look with the real data (THAT DOESN'T WORK! :'3)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`estudiantes` should be a local `state` of the component. Therefore, it needs to be captured as a state and use it for table data rendering as follows.

`setEstudiantes` is a `setState` function which updates the state asynchornously. Therefore, in order to check the updated state, you need to have the `console.log("estudiantes: ", estudiantes)` inside the render method (not after `setEstudiantes(tempData)`). Otherwise, you won't be able to see the updated state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import "./ListadoEstudiantes.css";
import data from "./mock-data.json";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Checkbox } from "@material-ui/core";

function ListadoEstudiantes({ user }) {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data);
  const [estudiantes, setEstudiantes] = useState([]);
  const history = useHistory("");

  const crearEstudiante = () => {
    history.push("/Crear_Estudiante");
  };

  const realizarPedidos = () => {
    history.push("/Crear_Pedidos");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("usuarios")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection("estudiantes")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
          const tempData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          tempData.push(data);

          console.log(doc.data());
          console.log("Temp Data: ", tempData);
        });
        setEstudiantes(tempData);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("estudiantes: ", estudiantes);

  return (
    <div className="listadoEstudiantes">
      <div className="estudiantes_container">
        <h1 className="estudiantes_container_h1">Listado de estudiantes</h1>
        <button onClick={crearEstudiante} className="crear_estudiante_boton">
          Crear Estudiantes
        </button>
        <h3 className="estudiantes_container_h3">
          *Para realizar su pedido seleccione a los estudiantes
        </h3>
        <div className="tableContainer">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr className="Lista">
                <th>
                  <input type="checkbox"></input>
                </th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Colegio</th>
                <th>Grado</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {estudiantes.map((e) => (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        let checked = event.target.checked;
                      }}
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked=""
                    ></input>
                  </td>

                  <td>{e.name}</td>
                  <td>{e.school}</td>
                  <td>{e.grade}</td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div className="space" />
        <button onClick={realizarPedidos} className="crear_estudiante_boton">
          Realizar Pedidos
        </button>
        <div className="space" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListadoEstudiantes;
```

Comment: So the key component was to set up estudiantes as a set state and then use a temp variable to hold the array and then set it up on the state, did I got it right?, Thank you very much if I told you I been stuck DAYS on that you wouldn't believe me

Comment: That's correct. Better study more on `state` and `props` handling in react which would come in handy if you're working more on react.

Comment: Yeah I just started to learn by my own and I tend to get stuck in very specific things which is a bit troublesome but learning on the way.

Comment: Quick question since is related and I think is not a big deal to make it a new question (maybe it is I might be wrong) but why does the data disappear when I refresh? it works fine unless I refresh.

Comment: When you refresh it will unmount the component and re-mount it again. Therefore, it will be back to the initial state which means your state is just an empty array. During the initial rendering, or during the mounting phase, component will call the useEffect function and get the data from db. Untill it receive the data and fill the table, your table remains without any data. Once the data fetched from db, then it will re-fill your table.

Comment: And is there a way to keep the data after refreshing ? I read that cookies and that kind of stuff can fix it, but for a local project/practice project is there anything else ?

Comment: Yes it's possible to keep the data fetched from backend in cookies, local storage or sessio storage (check there differences). But in your case, you're fetching data that could be updated in the database. If you kept them in your browser storage for the life time of the stored data, then you won't be able to capture the changes that happened in the stored data of the database.

Comment: Therefore, you can use a loader untill the data retrieval is completed. Then you won't see an empty table but a loader which shows until your application loads the data. You can have `antd` or `material-ui` libraries table component. It comes with an embedded loader. Such libraries would make your life easier when developing react applications.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll look forward to that when I finish this app I still have a lot of things to learn. I have work with the material UI library before but only for icons and that kind of things never though about using the tables.